# Combine two data frames based on columes, keep all variables from each dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames that need to combine together, an example shown below:

DF1
`Name Symbole Weight Length`
`Apple   Ap     0.5    0.5`
`Oranage Or     0.3    0.4`
`Banana  Ba     0.2    0.6`

DF2
`Name Symbole Volumn`
`Apple   Ap    0.52`
`Grape   Gr    0.3`
`Banana  Ba    0.35`

Expected Output
`Name Symbole Weight Length Volumn`
`Apple   Ap    0.5     0.5   0.52`
`Oranage Or    0.3     0.4   NA`
`Banana  Ba    0.2     0.6   0.35`
`Grape   Gr    NA      NA    0.3`

I tried: `Res <- inner_join(DF1, DF2, by = c("Name", "Symbole"))`, but the output is only the common rows.

I alos tried: `Res <- DF2 %>% right_join(DF1, by=c("Name","Symbole"))`, but it is adding the common rows into the dataframe.

Sorry that I use code as table in the post, since I think this may be better to explain my needs.
Thanks all.

Comment: please format the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana"),
                  Symbole = c("Ap", "Or", "Ba"),
                  Weight = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2),
                  Length = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.6))

DF2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Apple", "Grape", "Banana"),
                  Symbole = c("Ap", "Gr", "Ba"),
                  Volumn = c(0.52, 0.3, 0.35))

Res <- full_join(DF1, DF2, by = c("Name", "Symbole"))
Res
```

Output:

```
    Name Symbole Weight Length Volumn
1  Apple      Ap    0.5    0.5   0.52
2 Orange      Or    0.3    0.4     NA
3 Banana      Ba    0.2    0.6   0.35
4  Grape      Gr     NA     NA   0.30
```

Comment: What about if some of the rows has multiple names, for example: on DF2, the cell at row 1 name is "Apple;Fuji", and Symbole is "Ap;Fu". Since Apple;Fuji is still included in Apple, and I still expecting the same output. It will be even better if the results shows "Apple;Fuji", instead of showing "Apple".